# Using Affine Transform on Graphics2D Objects

Tags: java, swing, affinetransform

I am new to AffineTransform but I spent a couple of hours and kind of figured out how to get it to do what I want.  Basically my goal is the make a JInternal Frame that scales the Graphics2D objects when it is minimized.  For proof of concept I have created some code that scales with the mouse wheel and is translated on a mouse drag.

My question is, how can I package this into a JInternalFrame that scales when the JInternalFrame is minimized?  Also, is there a better way to do what I want to do?

Self contained example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class AffineTransformTest {

    private static TransformingCanvas canvas;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TransformingCanvas.initializePointList();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        canvas = new TransformingCanvas(TransformingCanvas.POINT_LIST);
        TranslateHandler translator = new TranslateHandler();
        canvas.addMouseListener(translator);
        canvas.addMouseMotionListener(translator);
        canvas.addMouseWheelListener(new ScaleHandler());
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(750, 750);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class TransformingCanvas extends JComponent {
        private double translateX;
        private double translateY;
        private double scale;
        private final int PREF_W = 800; //Window width
        private final int PREF_H = 800; //Window height
        private static final Color INACTIVE_COLOR = Color.RED;
        private static final Color ACTIVE_COLOR = Color.green;
        private java.util.List<Point> points;
        private java.util.List<Ellipse2D> ellipses = new ArrayList<>();
        private Map<Ellipse2D, Color> ellipseColorMap = new HashMap<>();
        public static java.util.List<Point> POINT_LIST = new ArrayList<>();

        /*
        * This loop will initialize POINT_LIST with the set of points for drawing the ellipses.
        * The for each loop initializes points for the top row and the second for loop draws the
        * right triangle.
        */
        protected static void initializePointList() {

            int ellipsePointsYCoordinate[] = {140, 200, 260, 320, 380, 440, 500, 560, 620};
            int ellipsePointsXCoordinate[] = {140, 200, 260, 320, 380, 440, 500, 560, 620, 680};
            int xx = 80;

            for (int aXt : ellipsePointsXCoordinate) {
                POINT_LIST.add(new Point(aXt, xx));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < ellipsePointsYCoordinate.length; i++) {
                for (int j = i; j < ellipsePointsYCoordinate.length; j++) {
                    POINT_LIST.add(new Point(ellipsePointsXCoordinate[i], ellipsePointsYCoordinate[j]));
                }
            }
        }

            TransformingCanvas() {
            translateX = 0;
            translateY = 0;
            scale = 1;
            setOpaque(true);
            setDoubleBuffered(true);
        }

        public TransformingCanvas(java.util.List<Point> points) {
            this.points = points;
            int OVAL_WIDTH = 30;

            for (Point p : points) {

                int x = p.x - OVAL_WIDTH / 2;
                int y = p.y - OVAL_WIDTH / 2;
                int w = OVAL_WIDTH;
                int h = OVAL_WIDTH;
                Ellipse2D ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, w, h);
                ellipses.add(ellipse);
                ellipseColorMap.put(ellipse, INACTIVE_COLOR);
            }
        }

        @Override public void paint(Graphics g) {

            AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();
            tx.translate(translateX, translateY);
            tx.scale(scale, scale);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.fillRect(0,0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g2.setTransform(tx);
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            for (Ellipse2D ellipse : ellipses) {
                g2.setColor(ellipseColorMap.get(ellipse));
                g2.fill(ellipse);
                g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
                g2.draw(ellipse);
            }

            /*
            * Set the font characteristics, color, and draw the row labels.
            */
            g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 18));
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

            //NOTE to self: add label DrawStrings back

            //Draws a 3DRect around the top row of ellipse2D objects
            g2.setColor(Color.lightGray);
            g2.draw3DRect(120, 60, 580, 40, true);
            g2.draw3DRect(121, 61, 578, 38, true);
            g2.draw3DRect(122, 62, 576, 36, true);
            //super.paint(g);
        }
    }

    private static class TranslateHandler implements MouseListener,
            MouseMotionListener {
        private int lastOffsetX;
        private int lastOffsetY;

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // capture starting point
            lastOffsetX = e.getX();
            lastOffsetY = e.getY();
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

            // new x and y are defined by current mouse location subtracted
            // by previously processed mouse location
            int newX = e.getX() - lastOffsetX;
            int newY = e.getY() - lastOffsetY;

            // increment last offset to last processed by drag event.
            lastOffsetX += newX;
            lastOffsetY += newY;

            // update the canvas locations
            canvas.translateX += newX;
            canvas.translateY += newY;

            // schedule a repaint.
            canvas.repaint();
        }

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
    }

    private static class ScaleHandler implements MouseWheelListener {
        public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
            if(e.getScrollType() == MouseWheelEvent.WHEEL_UNIT_SCROLL) {

                // make it a reasonable amount of zoom
                // .1 gives a nice slow transition
                canvas.scale += (.1 * e.getWheelRotation());
                // don't cross negative threshold.
                // also, setting scale to 0 has bad effects
                canvas.scale = Math.max(0.00001, canvas.scale);
                canvas.repaint();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify: Your intention is that the contents of the internal frames always stays the same, is this right? So if you initially have a frame with (usable) size of 100x100, and draw a rectangle of size 100x100 (completely filling the painting area), and then resize the frame to 200x200, then you want to apply a *scaling* to the graphics so that the rectangle is no longer painted with a size of 100x100, but with a size of 200x200, is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't fully get why you would want to scale the `Graphics` when they're not visible, but here is a rough instruction how to do it:

1. Set a `JDesktopPane` as the `JFrame`'s contentpane.
2. Create a `JInternalFrame` and add it do the `JDesktopPane`
3. Add a `InternalFrameListener` to the internal frame and then you can put inside the `public void internalFrameIconified(InternalFrameEvent arg0)` method everything you want to do if the internal frame was minimized.

Here is this implemented in your code (without any `AffineTransform` yet, just be basic concept):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent;
import javax.swing.event.InternalFrameListener;

public class AffineTransformTest {

    private static TransformingCanvas canvas;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TransformingCanvas.initializePointList();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        canvas = new TransformingCanvas(TransformingCanvas.POINT_LIST);
        JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane();
        TranslateHandler translator = new TranslateHandler();
        canvas.addMouseListener(translator);
        canvas.addMouseMotionListener(translator);
        canvas.addMouseWheelListener(new ScaleHandler());
        MyInternalFrame iFrame = new MyInternalFrame();
        iFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        iFrame.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        iFrame.setVisible(true);
        desktop.add(iFrame);
        frame.setContentPane(desktop);
        frame.setSize(750, 750);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class TransformingCanvas extends JComponent {
        private double translateX;
        private double translateY;
        private double scale;
        private final int PREF_W = 800; // Window width
        private final int PREF_H = 800; // Window height
        private static final Color INACTIVE_COLOR = Color.RED;
        private static final Color ACTIVE_COLOR = Color.green;
        private java.util.List<Point> points;
        private java.util.List<Ellipse2D> ellipses = new ArrayList<>();
        private Map<Ellipse2D, Color> ellipseColorMap = new HashMap<>();
        public static java.util.List<Point> POINT_LIST = new ArrayList<>();

        /*
         * This loop will initialize POINT_LIST with the set of points for
         * drawing the ellipses. The for each loop initializes points for the
         * top row and the second for loop draws the right triangle.
         */
        protected static void initializePointList() {

            int ellipsePointsYCoordinate[] = { 140, 200, 260, 320, 380, 440,
                    500, 560, 620 };
            int ellipsePointsXCoordinate[] = { 140, 200, 260, 320, 380, 440,
                    500, 560, 620, 680 };
            int xx = 80;

            for (int aXt : ellipsePointsXCoordinate) {
                POINT_LIST.add(new Point(aXt, xx));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < ellipsePointsYCoordinate.length; i++) {
                for (int j = i; j < ellipsePointsYCoordinate.length; j++) {
                    POINT_LIST.add(new Point(ellipsePointsXCoordinate[i],
                            ellipsePointsYCoordinate[j]));
                }
            }
        }

        TransformingCanvas() {
            translateX = 0;
            translateY = 0;
            scale = 1;
            setOpaque(true);
            setDoubleBuffered(true);
        }

        public TransformingCanvas(java.util.List<Point> points) {
            this.points = points;
            int OVAL_WIDTH = 30;

            for (Point p : points) {

                int x = p.x - OVAL_WIDTH / 2;
                int y = p.y - OVAL_WIDTH / 2;
                int w = OVAL_WIDTH;
                int h = OVAL_WIDTH;
                Ellipse2D ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, w, h);
                ellipses.add(ellipse);
                ellipseColorMap.put(ellipse, INACTIVE_COLOR);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {

            AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();
            tx.translate(translateX, translateY);
            tx.scale(scale, scale);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g2.setTransform(tx);
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            for (Ellipse2D ellipse : ellipses) {
                g2.setColor(ellipseColorMap.get(ellipse));
                g2.fill(ellipse);
                g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
                g2.draw(ellipse);
            }

            /*
             * Set the font characteristics, color, and draw the row labels.
             */
            g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 18));
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

            // NOTE to self: add label DrawStrings back

            // Draws a 3DRect around the top row of ellipse2D objects
            g2.setColor(Color.lightGray);
            g2.draw3DRect(120, 60, 580, 40, true);
            g2.draw3DRect(121, 61, 578, 38, true);
            g2.draw3DRect(122, 62, 576, 36, true);
            // super.paint(g);
        }
    }

    private static class TranslateHandler implements MouseListener,
            MouseMotionListener {
        private int lastOffsetX;
        private int lastOffsetY;

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // capture starting point
            lastOffsetX = e.getX();
            lastOffsetY = e.getY();
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

            // new x and y are defined by current mouse location subtracted
            // by previously processed mouse location
            int newX = e.getX() - lastOffsetX;
            int newY = e.getY() - lastOffsetY;

            // increment last offset to last processed by drag event.
            lastOffsetX += newX;
            lastOffsetY += newY;

            // update the canvas locations
            canvas.translateX += newX;
            canvas.translateY += newY;

            // schedule a repaint.
            canvas.repaint();
        }

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        }
    }

    private static class ScaleHandler implements MouseWheelListener {
        public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {

        }
    }

    static class MyInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame implements
            InternalFrameListener {

        public MyInternalFrame() {
            super("iFrame", true, // resizable
                    true, // closable
                    true, // maximizable
                    true);// iconifiable
            setSize(300, 300);
            addInternalFrameListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void internalFrameActivated(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void internalFrameClosed(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void internalFrameDeactivated(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void internalFrameDeiconified(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void internalFrameIconified(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("Minimized");


            //What you want to  do
        }

        @Override
        public void internalFrameOpened(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {

        }
    }
}
```

If now you still can't achieve what you want, please explain further, as I don't really see the point of scaling Graphics that are not visible.

### Edit:

Now that I understand what the real question was: You can add a `ComponentListener` to your `JInternalFrame`. Then put inside the `public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {` method everything that you want to change (probably the variables of the width and height of the `Graphics`). Use the code above, just change the `MyInternalFrame` class to this:

```
static class MyInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame implements
        ComponentListener {

    public MyInternalFrame() {
        super("iFrame", true, // resizable
                true, // closable
                true, // maximizable
                true);// iconifiable
        setSize(300, 300);
        addComponentListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Resized");
        System.out.println("Width: " + getWidth());
        System.out.println("Height: " + getHeight());
        System.out.println();

    }

    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {

    }


}
```

### Edit 2:

I'll give you an idea of how you could make it resize (change the `componentResized` method to this):

```
@Override
public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
    String str = "";
    if (getWidth() < 1000) {
        str = "0." + getWidth();
    } else {
        str = "1." + (getWidth()-1000);
        System.out.println(getWidth()-1000);
    }
    double dou = Double.parseDouble(str);
    canvas.scale = dou;
}
```

Comment: they become visible when you scroll the mouse wheel.

Comment: @feltersnach Yeah, in your example they do. But your questions was how to "*make a JInternal Frame that scales the Graphics2D objects when it is minimized*" - If this is really your goal you just have to scale the `Graphics` in the `public void internalFrameIconified(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {` method in my example.

Comment: I see the confusion now.  I said minimized but I really wanted the graphics to scale when "not maximized."  (if that makes sense)  So that when I make the JInternalFrame smaller the graphics get smaller.  Thanks for your help with exactly what I asked for though.

Comment: @feltersnach That's also possible. I will edit my question to also answer that.

Comment: I am looking at my code to figure out why the graphics are not initially visible prior to the mouseWheel events.  Do you see anything that stands out?

Comment: @feltersnach Yeah, sorry I put that part out. Just copy the code that you had inside the `ScaleHandler` before and paste it in my example again. I also edited my question.

Comment: I have been working on this all morning and I can't get it to scale when I resize the internal frame.  It either didplays my graphics and won't scale or has no visible graphics at all, no matter what I try.

Comment: Thanks, you are really good.  I appreciate your time and helping me learn some new concepts.